# "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" while using array

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, error-handling

I have a tuple of indices `dout = (50,32,16,16)` and would like to use it in the function `dout[i,j,k,l]` which I have defined in a for loop. How can I convert this tuple so that it can be used for the values `i,j,k,l` when called?

Error code:

```
for i in range(N):
  for j in range(F):
    for l in range(height):
        for k in range(width):
            chain_grad = dout[i,j,l,k]  *Here is where the error happens*
            t = x_padded[i,:,l*stride:l*stride + HH,k*stride:k*stride + WW]
            rr = w[j] * chain_grad
```

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: show the actual error and code.  The error says you are trying to index a tuple with a tuple.

Comment: To clarify, it means that either `i`, `j`, `l` or `k` is not an integer.

Comment: `dout` is a tuple (as you state in the first line).  `dout[2]` works, `dout[1,2]` raises this error. If `dout` was a 4d array, then `dout[i,j,l,k]` would work.  Otherwise I don't know what you are trying to do in this line.